# Django Fieldsets Error when customizing the Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I was trying to customize a model in my Django Application but was getting this error.

```
<class 'core.admin.DemoAdmin'>: (admin.E008) The value of 'fieldsets[0][1]['fields']' must be a list or tuple.
```

models.py

```
class DemoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =  ('name', 'city')
    fieldsets = (
            ('standard info', {
                'fields': ('name')
                }),
            ('Adress info', {
                'fields': ('address', ('city', 'zipp'))
                }),
        )

admin.site.register(Demo, DemoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that Django expected me to include a comma after the tuple.

Changing the admnin.py to the below code snippets fixes the error.

```
class DemoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =  ('name', 'city')
    fieldsets = (
            ('standard info', {
                'fields': ('name',)
                }),
            ('Adress info', {
                'fields': ('address', ('city', 'zipp'),)
                }),
        )

admin.site.register(Demo, DemoAdmin)
```

Hopes it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I have been battling  with a similar issues and this helped to fix my problem.